# creating dataframe specific schema : StructField starting with capital letter

Tags: python, schema, azure-databricks, pyspark

Apologies for the lengthy post for a seemingly simple curiosity, but I wanted to give full context...

In Databricks, I am creating a "row" of data based on a specific schema definition, and then inserting that row into an empty dataframe (also based on the same specific schema).

The schema definition looks like this:

```
myschema_xb = StructType(
  [
    StructField("_xmlns", StringType(), True),
    StructField("_Version", DoubleType(), True),
    StructField("MyIds",
      ArrayType(
        StructType(
          [
            StructField("_ID", StringType(), True),
            StructField("_ID_Context", StringType(), True),
            StructField("_Type", LongType(), True),
          ]
        ),
        True
      ),
      True
    ),
  ]
)
```

And the row entry is thusly:

```
myRow = Row(
    _xmlns="http://some.where.com",
    _Version=12.3,
    MyIds=[
        Row(
          _ID="XY",
          _ID_Context="Exxwhy",
          _Type=9
        ),
        Row(
          _ID="9152",
          _ID_Context="LNUMB",
          _Type=21
        ),
    ]
)
```

Lastly, the databricks notebook code is:

```
mydf = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), myschema_xb)
rows = [myRow]
rdf = spark.createDataFrame(rows, myschema_xb)
appended = mydf.union(rdf)
```

The call to `rdf = spark.createDataFrame(rows, myschema_xb)` causes an exception:

`ValueError: Unexpected tuple 'h' with StructType`.

Now the part I am curious about is if I change the element `MyIds` to `myIds` (ie. lower case the first letter), the code **works**, and my new dataframe (`appended`) has the single row of data.

What is this exception mean & why does it go away when I change the case of my element?

(FYI, our databricks runtime environment is Scala 2.11)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue should be from how Row objects sort the keys/fields, from the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Row):

> Row can be used to create a row object by using named arguments, the fields will be sorted by names.

In `myschema_xb`, the three columns are defined in the order `[_xmlns, _Version, MyIds]`. When you define myRow with the keys: `(_xmlns, _Version, MyIds)`, the actual Row object generated will be:

```
Row(MyIds=[Row(_ID='XY', _ID_Context='Exxwhy', _Type=9), Row(_ID='9152', _ID_Context='LNUMB', _Type=21)], _Version=12.3, _xmlns='http://some.where.com')
```

Which has `MyIds` moved to the first column and this does not match the schema and thus yields ERROR. While when you use lowercase column-name `myIds`, the keys in Row object are sorted as `['_Version', '_xmlns', 'myIds']` which had `myIds` in the right column, but `_Version` and `_xmls` switched. This does not yield error since simple datatype can pass through the typecasting, but the resulting dataframe is incorrect.

To overcome this issue, you should set up a Row-like class and customize the order of keys to make sure the order of fields matches exactly with those shown in your schema:

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

MyOuterROW = Row('_xmlns', '_Version', 'MyIds')
MyInnerRow = Row('_ID', '_ID_Context', '_Type')

myRow = MyOuterROW( 
    "http://some.where.com", 
    12.3, 
    [ 
        MyInnerROW("XY", "Exxwhy", 9), 
        MyInnerROW("9152", "LNUMB", 21) 
    ] 
)              
print(myRow)
#Row(_xmlns='http://some.where.com', _Version=12.3, MyIds=[Row(_ID='XY', _ID_Context='Exxwhy', _Type=9), Row(_ID='9152', _ID_Context='LNUMB', _Type=21)])

rdf = spark.createDataFrame([myRow], schema=myschema_xb)
```