# RDD(array(list())) to be mapped to fields and its values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I was trying to process the data but stuck with below scenario please help

Expecting solution in pyspark

I have sample rdd as below

```py
[Row(columnnames=['user_id', 'user_name', 'first_name', 'last_name',  'is_active'], columnvalues=['100', 'name@companyname.com', 'empname', 'lastname' 'true'])]
```

I want final dataframe to be as below

```py
# +------+------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+-----------------
# |  user_id|user_name             |   first_name  |          last_name|  is_active
# +------+------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+---------------------
# |100      |  name@companyname.com|   ram     |         laxman|         true
# +------+------+-------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------
```

In above I am trying to map column names to column values as a fields and values

How can I achived in pyspark? Can some one suggest how to reach the solution?

Comment: try: `rdd.map(lambda row: Row(**dict(zip(row.columnnames, row.columnvalues)))).toDF()`

Comment: hi thanks for u r response
its working without toDF() at the end.if i use toDF() i am getting below error
  @jxc
return sparkSession.createDataFrame(self, schema, sampleRatio)
rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare)_createFromRDD
    struct = self._inferSchema(rdd, samplingRatio, names=schema)
/server/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 377, in _inferSchema
    raise ValueError("Some of types cannot be determined by the "
ValueError: Some of types cannot be determined by the first 100 rows, please try again with sampling

Comment: so i am preparing struct schema and creating dataframe with spark.createdataframe(rdd,schema)

Comment: if my rdd as below [Row(kind=update,columnnames=['user_id', 'user_name', 'first_name', 'last_name',  'is_active'], columnvalues=['100', 'name@companyname.com', 'empname', 'lastname' 'true'])] 
and i want kind to be another column with 'update' value how can i do that??

Comment: the error is from how the keys for Row objects are sorted, this could be an issue if you explicitly specify the schema, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59147146/9510729. if the columnnames are always the same list, you can set myRow = Row('kind', 'user_id', 'user_name', 'first_name', 'last_name',  'is_active'), and then `rdd.map(lambda x: myRow(x.kind, *x.columnvalues)).toDF()`

Comment: @jxc got it.thank you for your response will test the above usecase and  post you update